# Wordpress - Meta Field Update

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a couple meta fields in Wordpress for a Custom Post Type.  They are 'Price' and 'Details'.  If I got to the 'edit post' page, and i change something in one of these fields, but then decide to just leave the page by hitting 'back' in the browser or closing the window, i get a warning from my browser "are you sure you want to leave the page?".  When I hit 'Yes', it erases anything that's in those 2 fields, even what was previously stored before my editing.

Any idea why this could be?

Here's some of my code in functions.php:

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
function admin_init()
    {
        add_meta_box("price", "Price", "price_field", "product", "normal", "high");
        add_meta_box("details", "Details", "details_field", "product", "normal", "high");
    }

    function price_field()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $price = $custom["price"][0];
        ?>
        <label>Price: $</label>
        <input name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
        <?php
    }

    function details_field()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $details = $custom["details"][0];
        ?>
        <label>Details:</label>
        <input name="details" rows='5' value="<?php echo $details; ?>" />
        <?php
    }


    /*--------------------------------*/
    /* Save PRICE and DETAILS fields */
    /*--------------------------------*/
    add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
    function save_details()
    {
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "details", $_POST["details"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didnt add filtering in your save details method. Remember action hook "save_post" is also called once the post is auto save in draft even if you didnt click the update or the publish button. Try this

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

 function save_details($post_id){
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;

        // uncomment if youre using nonce
        //if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
          //       return;


        // Check permissions
        //change the "post" with your custom post type
        if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] )
        {
           if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
                return;
        }
        else
        {
           if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
                return;
        }

      //if success go to your process
      //you can erase your global $post and dont use $post->ID rather change it with $post_id since its our parameter
      update_post_meta($post_id, "price", $_POST["price"]);
      update_post_meta($post_id, "details", $_POST["details"]);
 }
```

**NOTE:** in **if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] )** line, change "post" to your post type

Comment: Awesome!  That worked great.  You're right, i didn't account for autosave